# According to reactive functional paradigm

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have following function:

```
_processCalenderSelect: function (oCalendarSelectOb, oEditButton) {
  let self = this;

  return oCalendarSelectOb
    .switchMap(function (oCalendar) {
      return oEditButton.getPressed()? Rx.Observable.of(oCalendar) : Rx.Observable.never();
    })
    .mergeMap(function (oCalendar) {
      return Rx.Observable.from(oCalendar.getSource().getSelectedDates());
    })
    .map(function (oDateRange) {
      return oDateRange.getStartDate();
    });

},
```

the first parameter is just an observable and the second is an object.

Look at the `switchMap` method, I am asking if the button is pressed or not.

My question is, do I break Reactive Functional Paradigm, when I ask for the button state inside the closure?

```
.switchMap(function (oCalendar) {
      return oEditButton.getPressed()? Rx.Observable.of(oCalendar) : Rx.Observable.never();
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your streams are triggered, this is "technically O.k.", however as you probably already guessed, you are kind of breaking the "spirit" of having pure, stateless functions by introducing a non-stream-state, the `oEditButton` - the stream cannot be guaranteed to have the same result with the same inputs every time, because there is some "external" state(button pressed or not).

So the "cleaner" approach would be (unsure if that works for your application) to have something like an `oEditButtonClicked$`-event-stream, that will trigger processing of selected dates.

```
oEditButtonClicked$
    .switchMapTo(oCalenderSelect$)
    .mergeMap(cal => Rx.Obserbalbe.from(cal.getSource....))
```

---

As a side-note, if you are not able to introduce that event-stream, you could still improve your code by using `skipWhile`:

```
return oCalendarSelectOb
    .skipWhile(() => oEditButton.getPressed())
    .mergeMap(function (oCalendar) {
      return Rx.Observable.from(oCalendar.getSource().getSelectedDates());
    })
    .map(function (oDateRange) {
      return oDateRange.getStartDate();
    });
```

(this does NOT resolve the initial question though, just a hint on the side)

Comment: The stream will be triggered, when someone select date on calendar.

Comment: I implemented the first suggestion above and it works as expected. Thanks so much. It is so difficult for a beginner to know, what is possible with rxjs.

Comment: Almost everything is possible - this question is more like a matter of personal taste and a how "perfect" you want your code to be - but from a strictly technical aspect your code should have been working fine already for your usecase.

Comment: But my goal is, to use rxjs in the right way, not breaking the paradigm. Thanks a lot.